# Can't get keyboard height when using Interactive keyboard dismissal

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I have been trying to implement interactive keyboard like in 'iMessages' app Something like this; 
 [image: This]

I need to continuously get exact frame of keyboard when sliding it up or down.

I have already tried; 
 keyboardWillChangeFrame, keyboardDidChangeFrame, keyboardWillShowForResizing, keyboardWillHideForResizing, keyboardWillShow, keyboardWillBeHidden 
 None of them continuously return the frame. What is the best way to catch that frame?

Comment: Could you please check my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

That's a tricky & Simple.

ViewController inherits  `UIResponder`

`open class UIViewController : UIResponder, NSCoding, UIAppearanceContainer, UITraitEnvironment, UIContentContainer, UIFocusEnvironment`

So it can become first responder since it can have input accessory view too.

What you have to do is

1) Go to Storyboard -> ViewController and then select your tableview and change keyboard dismiss type to

[image]

2) In your Viewcontroller

Add following code

```
var viewAcc : UIView? // That contains TextFied and send button

override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
    return viewAcc
}



override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
    return true
}
```

For you I have created simple Textfield and send button as example you can modify it with your's

```
 func setupView () {


    self.tblChatDetail.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 20, 0)


    viewAcc = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 44))
    viewAcc?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    textView = UITextView (frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:0,height: 44 - 0.5))
    textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(4, 3, 3, 3)
    textView.delegate = self
    viewAcc?.backgroundColor = .lightGray


    viewAcc?.addSubview(textView);

    sendButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    sendButton.isEnabled = true
    sendButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)
    sendButton.setTitle("Send", for: .normal)
    sendButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 6, bottom: 6, right: 6)
    sendButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ChatDetailViewController.sendMessage), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    viewAcc?.addSubview(sendButton)


    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sendButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    viewAcc?.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textView, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: viewAcc, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 8))
    viewAcc?.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: viewAcc, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 7.5))
    viewAcc?.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textView, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: sendButton, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: -2))
    viewAcc?.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: viewAcc, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -8))
    viewAcc?.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: sendButton, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: viewAcc, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    viewAcc?.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: sendButton, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: viewAcc, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -4.5))


}
```

Just run and Bang on !!

Comment: I know it's already late but dude, Idk why this is not accepted as the right answer. You saved my day!

Comment: @hoangCap I am glad that solution working for you. May be person who asked question has not visited this question. But no worries :)

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya It doesnt push content upwards when keyboard is open. The question was about pushing content upwards when keyboard visible with interactive keyboard.

Comment: @BerkKaya You can create IBOutlet of bottom constraint of your tableview or collection view and add Keyboard will show and will hide notification. and change the constant value accordingly

Comment: It doesn't work with interactive keyboard. The content stucks at the same position until keyboard completely disappears.