# How to get List Interactive keyboard height in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, iphone, keyboard, uikit, swiftui

In `SwiftUI` we can let the keyboard be interactive in a `List` by swiping down. We only need to  provide this code to the init() of the view.

```swift
init() {
    UITableView.appearance().keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
}
```

This works fine but the view that is attached to the keyboard isn't moving with the keyboard itself.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48338709/cant-get-keyboard-height-when-using-interactive-keyboard-dismissal) post which should solve the issue in UIKit. How to I solve it in SwiftUI?

This is how I handle Keyboard popping up:

```swift
final class KeyboardResponder: ObservableObject {

    private var _center: NotificationCenter
    @Published private(set) var currentHeight: CGFloat = 0
    @Published private(set) var duration: Double = 0.0

    init(center: NotificationCenter = .default) {
        _center = center
        _center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyBoardWillShow(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        _center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyBoardWillHide(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    deinit {
        _center.removeObserver(self)
    }

    @objc func keyBoardWillShow(notification: Notification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue,
            let duration = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Double {
            self.duration = duration
            currentHeight = keyboardSize.height
        }
    }

    @objc func keyBoardWillHide(notification: Notification) {
        currentHeight = 0
    }
}

struct KeyboardHandler: ViewModifier {
    let height: CGFloat
    let duration: Double

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .padding(.bottom, height)
            .animation(.spring(blendDuration: duration))
    }
}
```